# Problem trying to add Search bar for simple SwiftUI app retrieving web data

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a small project which is an extension of a Swift UI exercise making a web call to Github from Greg Lim's book Beginning Swift UI:
https://github.com/ethamoos/GitProbe

I’ve been using this to practise basic skills and to try and add other features that could be useful in a realworld app.

My main change from the initial exercise was to add the option to choose which user to lookup (this was previously hardcoded) and allow the user to enter this. Because this can return a lot of data I would now like to make the resulting List .searchable so that the user can filter the results.

I’ve been following this tutorial here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-search-bar-to-filter-your-data

but I’ve realised that this is based upon the data being returned being Strings, and therefore the search is a string.

I am returning JSON decoded into a list of User data objects so a straight search does not work. I am assuming that I can adjust this to match a string search against my custom objects but I'm not sure how to do this.

To give you an idea of what I mean here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage


struct Result: Codable {
    let totalCount: Int
    let incompleteResults: Bool
    let items: [User]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
        case items
    }
}

struct User: Codable, Hashable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let nodeID: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let gravatarID: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, id
        case nodeID = "node_id"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case gravatarID = "gravatar_id"
    }
}


class FetchUsers: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    func search(for user:String) {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.github.com/search/users")!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: user)]
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = decodedData.items
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Enter user to search for")
                    TextField("Enter your username", text: $username).disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: UserView(username: username)) {
                    Text("Show detail for \(username)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserView: View {
    
    @State var username: String
    @ObservedObject var fetchUsers = FetchUsers()
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(fetchUsers.users, id:\.self) { user in
                NavigationLink(user.login, destination: UserDetailView(user:user))
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.fetchUsers.search(for: username)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .navigationTitle("Users")
        
    }

/// With suggestion added 


    /// The search results
    private var searchResults: [User] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return fetchUsers.users // your entire list of users if no search input
        } else {
            return fetchUsers.search(for: searchText) // calls your search method passing your search text
        }
    }
}

struct UserDetailView: View {
    
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(user.login).font(.headline)
            Text("Git iD = \(user.id)")
            URLImage(URL(string:user.avatarURL)!){ image in
                image.resizable().frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your UserListView is not properly constructed. I don't see why you would need a ScrollView with an empty text inside? I removed that.

So I removed searchText from the View to the FetchUsers class so we can delay the server requests thus avoiding unnecessary multiple calls. Please adjust it to your needs (check [Apple's Debounce documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/debounce(for:scheduler:options:)). Everything should work as expected now.

```
import Combine

class FetchUsers: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    @Published var searchText = ""
    
    var subscription: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    init() {
        $searchText
            .debounce(for: .milliseconds(500), scheduler: RunLoop.main) // debounces the string publisher, delaying requests and avoiding unnecessary calls.
            .removeDuplicates()
            .map({ (string) -> String? in
                if string.count < 1 {
                    self.users = [] // cleans the list results when empty search
                    return nil
                }
                return string
            }) // prevents sending numerous requests and sends nil if the count of the characters is less than 1.
            .compactMap{ $0 } // removes the nil values
            .sink { (_) in
                //
            } receiveValue: { [self] text in
                search(for: text)
            }.store(in: &subscription)
    }
    
    func search(for user:String) {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.github.com/search/users")!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: user.lowercased())]
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data received")
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.users = decodedData.items
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct UserListView: View {
    
    @State var username: String
    @ObservedObject var fetchUsers = FetchUsers()

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(fetchUsers.users, id:\.self) { user in
                    NavigationLink(user.login, destination: UserDetailView(user:user))
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $fetchUsers.searchText) // we move the searchText to fetchUsers
            .navigationTitle("Users")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. 

I think something is still not right in my code, though.

To make it easier I've added the entire code compressed into a single screen. I've updated the original post.

Comment: The error I get back is:

`Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type '[User]'`

So I'm thinking there is still something wrong with the way the search is constructed?

Comment: Hmm… your search is updating users list directly instead of returning the values. Change the method to return the users array.

Comment: Would you mind showing what you mean - I'm getting:
`Unexpected non-void return value in void function` when I try to make the search function return users

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer and included Combine to delay your requests to the server and still receive your data correctly. Everything related to the search is in FetchUsers and should work properly.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion @André Henrique da Silva
I'll check it out.

Comment: Hey @ethamoose Have you checked it out? Can you please validate my answer if so... Thanks!

Comment: Hi  @André Henrique da Silva,

It’s probably my own limitations but I’ve not been able to implement your code into my version, I’m afraid. It builds but the search isn’t working.

I really appreciate your effort but there are a few new things you’ve added that I don’t understand, so it’s quite difficult for me to identify what the issue is. 

I was really just looking for the most basic solution to allow the searchResults to to work as a filter, as that much I understand, but it may be that what I’m asking is not possible without re-factoring the main class, as you suggest.

Comment: I can give more info if you like, but I understand if you don’t want to do any more at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I think I've figured this out - thanks to the suggestions from Andre.

I need to correctly filter my data and then return the remainder.

Here's the corrected (abridged) version:

```
import SwiftUI
import URLImage


struct Result: Codable {
    let totalCount: Int
    let incompleteResults: Bool
    let items: [User]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case totalCount = "total_count"
        case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
        case items
    }
}

struct User: Codable, Hashable {
    let login: String
    let id: Int
    let nodeID: String
    let avatarURL: String
    let gravatarID: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, id
        case nodeID = "node_id"
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case gravatarID = "gravatar_id"
    }
}

class FetchUsers: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    func search(for user:String) {
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.github.com/search/users")!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: user)]
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
            return
//            print("error")
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.users = decodedData.items
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Enter user to search for")
                    TextField("Enter your username", text: $username).disableAutocorrection(true)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: UserView(username: username)) {
                    Text("Show detail for \(username)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserView: View {
    
    @State var username: String
    @ObservedObject var fetchUsers = FetchUsers()
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(searchResults, id:\.self) { user in
                NavigationLink(user.login, destination: UserDetailView(user:user))
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.fetchUsers.search(for: username)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .navigationTitle("Users")
    }
    
    var searchResults: [User] {
         if searchText.isEmpty {
             print("Search is empty")
             return fetchUsers.users
         } else {
             print("Search has a value - is filtering")
             return fetchUsers.users.filter { $0.login.contains(searchText) }
         }
     }
}

struct UserDetailView: View {
    
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text(user.login).font(.headline)
            Text("Git iD = \(user.id)")
            URLImage(URL(string:user.avatarURL)!){ image in
                image.resizable().frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```